# Using a Dynamic List Validation in VBA

Tags: validation, vba

I'm new to programing in VBA and I'm trying to validate data with a list in an Excel worksheet. The problem is the list varies in size every time I select a different criteria from a drop-down list.

For example: when I select China, the list turns into 10 different sellers. Range A1 to A10, but when I select Japan I only have 5 sellers, from A1 to A5.

So I need a new range in the the **Formula1** part each time.

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$Z$1:$Z$30"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

What would be the best way to do this?

I know if I leave a fixed range it can work but it doesn´t look OK, because it leaves a lot of empty spaces and it doesn't look neat.

I hope it´s understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the las non empty cell of the column with something like this

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown)
```

Then you just build your Formula1 properties from A1 to the result.

```
Dim strFormula1 as string
strFormula1 = "=$A$1:" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address()
```

Hope it helps, have not tested might have errors

Answer (score 1):

Use a Named Range with formula

To create a Name go to Formula / Name Manager / New

Choise a name, for example DataValidation, in RefersTo use

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$Z$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$Z:$Z),1)
```

Now, you have a dynamic interval , and can use on your validation.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are simpler, but will not work if you ever have non-continous non-blank cells that need to be in the validation list.  This method should overcome that :)

You could use a custom function in VBA to return the filtered string address. This will return the filtered address, or it will return the original address **IF** the filtered address is not a valid range.

**NOTE** This will likely fail if the returned address exceeds the 255-character limit.

```
With Selection.Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
xlBetween, Formula1:=GetAddress(Range("$Z$1:$Z$30"))
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
.InputTitle = ""
.ErrorTitle = ""
.InputMessage = ""
.ErrorMessage = ""
.ShowInput = True
.ShowError = True
End With
```

Place the function in a normal code module.

```
Function GetAddress(myRange As Range) As String

Dim cl As Range
Dim c As Long: c = 1
Dim tmpAddress As String

For Each cl In myRange
    If cl.Value <> vbNullString Then
        'Create a string value of cell address matching criteria'
        If tmpAddress = vbNullString Then
            tmpAddress = myRange.Cells(c).Address
        Else:
            tmpAddress = tmpAddress & "," & myRange.Cells(c).Address
        End If
    End If
    c = c + 1
Next

If Not Range(tmpAddress) Is Nothing Then
    GetAddress = "=" & tmpAddress
Else:
    MsgBox "There are no non-empty cells in this range.", vbInformation
    GetAddress = "=" & myRange.Address
End If

End Function
```

Comment: I'm sure your answer works perfect, but it´s to advanced for me :)

Comment: No problem.  The only thing this method can do which the others cannot, is that it allows your range to contain blank cells anywhere.  The other methods *require* that the range end at the very first blank cell.  If that's the extent of your problem, then the other answers are perfectly acceptable.  Cheers!

Comment: Exactly, in my case I will not have that problem, but I'll keep yours in mind for the future. Thnx again.