# Create dynamic validation list

Tags: excel, vba

Amongst the links I found, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882078/creating-dynamic-validation-list-using-vba-object-required) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199027/using-a-dynamic-list-validation-in-vba) appear to be similar to my question. Trying to implement the answers turned out futile!

I get an application defined error with the following code.

I'm looking to create a dynamic range with this code:

```
Dim strFormula1 As String
Dim d As Range
strFormula1 = "control!:$B$3:" & Sheet5.Range("b2").End(xlDown).Address()
Set d = Sheet1.Range("K3:K20000")
With d.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Formula1:="='" & strFormula1 & "'"
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the string being assigned to strFormula1 is incorrect.  It includes an extra colon between the sheet name and the range reference.

Secondly, the Formula1 argument is also incorrect.  In addition to having the colon in the wrong place, it has the apostrophe (') in the wrong pace as well.

Try the following instead...

```
Dim strFormula1 As String
Dim d As Range

With Sheet5
    strFormula1 = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Address(External:=True)
End With

Set d = Sheet1.Range("K3:K20000")

With d.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:="=" & strFormula1
End With
```

Comment: thanks a ton! that works now. Also, thank you for providing an explanation as to where I went wrong.